# Regular expressions Perl

Tags: regex, perl

regular expression that matches three consecutive copies of the regular expression
`foo|bar`. Your pattern should match `foofoofoo`, `foobarbar`, `barbarbar`

```
if($line!~m/((foo)+|(bar)+){0,3}/){print"No match\n";}
else
{   print "$`";       #print out first part of string
    print "<$&>";     #highlight the matching part
    print "$'";       #print out the rest
}
```

This is my expression, It works, but somehow it only check part the string.

For example:

Input `foo`: it will highlight `foo`

Input `foofdafdafbar`: it will only highlight `foo` but not `bar`

I need to check if either `foo` or `bar` exist, but i also i want to make sure when they both exist, they will both highlight

Comment: Your regexp only matches `foo` and `bar` when they are consecutive. In your second example, they are separated, so it only matches one of them.

Comment: Your regexp is also wrong. It will match more than 3 consecutive copies, because you have `+` inside the group.

Comment: the correct regexp is `(?:foo|bar){3}`

Comment: Would you mind me what is : mean?

Comment: `(?:` is like `(` except that it doesn't capture the contents (e.g. into `$1`); it is what you should use for grouping stuff unless you need to capture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex doesn't really make any sense, based off what you describe that you want.  Additionally, your secondary examples seem to contradict what you say you want in the first part.

Perhaps all you're looking for is?

```
if ($line =~ m/((?:foo|bar){3})/) {
```

Comment: Yes, I think I got the wrong idea of the question, Would you mind tell what : means. I know ? means start. Is there a different meaning for ?:

Comment: `(?: ... )` is a [`non-capturing group`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) as documented in perlretut.  Very useful anytime you have an or'd list.